# How to get the public objects

Tags: php, object, guzzle, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

I'm working on PHP with Rackspace API, this is what I have used here:

```
$file->setContent(fopen('sites/default/files/rackspace/' . $end_element, 'r+'));
$cdnUrl = $file->getPublicUrl();
print_r($cdnUrl);
```

And its returning me the below mentioned structure.

```
Guzzle\Http\Url Object
(
    [scheme:protected] => http
    [host:protected] => something.r2.cf3.rackcdn.com
    [port:protected] => 
    [username:protected] => 
    [password:protected] => 
    [path:protected] => /something-abc.jpg
    [fragment:protected] => 
    [query:protected] => Guzzle\Http\QueryString Object
        (
            [fieldSeparator:protected] => &
            [valueSeparator:protected] => =
            [urlEncode:protected] => RFC 3986
            [aggregator:protected] => 
            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

What I need here is something like this:

```
Guzzle\Http\Url Object
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => something.r2.cf3.rackcdn.com
    [port] => 
    [username] => 
    [password] => 
    [path] => /something-abc.jpg
    [fragment] => 
    [query] => Guzzle\Http\QueryString Object
        (
            [fieldSeparator] => &
            [valueSeparator] => =
            [urlEncode] => RFC 3986
            [aggregator] => 
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

So that at least I can use those objects, any suggestions?

Comment: The collection is loading as objects if like this means use    json_decode(array, true);

Comment: @Ramki, I've used this but it provided me blank output:

`$json_decode = json_decode($cdnUrl, true);
print_r($json_decode);`

Comment: @Ramki what are you talking about? its an object not json so `json_encode` can't do what he wants to achieve.

Comment: @tradyblix we can use json_encode to convert object to array

Comment: Rackspace api objects will have protected variables , either change it to public if you can or use accordingly.

Comment: @Rorschach, any idea how can I have the unprotected variables?

Comment: That's depends on your rackspace api.

Comment: @Ramki no, unless you cast the object as an array and then encode it and then you can decode it.

@RishiKulshreshtha have you tried to cast the response object as an array e.g. `$cdnUrl = (array)$cdnUrl;` although that will make the fields with `*` since its all protected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a `Guzzle\Http\Url` object, and you will not be able to access its protected or private properties. The class is [defined here](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle3/blob/master/src/Guzzle/Http/Url.php), so you can use any of the public methods to access its state.

You can also cast it to a string like so:

```
$stringUrl = (string) $url;
```

Or access other stuff:

```
$host   = $url->getHost();   // something.r2.cf3.rackcdn.com
$scheme = $url->getScheme(); // http
$port   = $url->getPort();
$path   = $url->getPath();   // something-abc.jpg
```

The query is represented by another object, `Guzzle\Http\QueryString`:

```
$query = $url->getQuery();
```

For more info on object visibility, please consult the [official docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Comment: Thanks @hohner, it worked.

`$cdnUrl = $file->getPublicUrl();
$stringUrl = (string) $cdnUrl;
print_r($stringUrl);`